# Changing the H1 tag on every page of the website

Tags: seo, h1

I have an e-commerce site that has 30,000 live products on it. The item name on the product page is the `h1` tag.

We're looking to change the item name formatting on the website, which means that 30,000 `h1` tags will be changed at the same time.

Is that a red flag to Google?

Comment: Short answer? No. Sweeping changes are made routinely on many sites. Just make sure that the header tag is semantically complete so that Google can figure out what you are talking about. For example, `Model X123` does not mean much, however, `Sony X123 Television` does. The more you can add to your h1 tag to signal what the page is about the better but do not get carried away. Google will use an ontology to understand the product and how it compares to others. Cheers!!

Comment: We've done this kind of change a few times in a ~6.000 paged site, the result was positive if we did something better.

Answer (score -2):

Too many H1 tags will drop your SEO ranking as they confuse the search engines. 
Best way is to use css and have custom tag (or say h2 tag) and increase the font-size to that of your current h1 styling. This will maintain your styling and also your SEO ranking.

Comment: The OP is talking about changing the h1 tags of many pages. Not about having more than one h1 tag. You are exactly correct regarding more than one h1 tag. Only one should ever exist. Cheers!!